# My tests don't work after switching between JUnit to TestNG

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, powermock

I can't understand why my code can't execute TestNG tests. At the same time when I use JUnit test (with corresponding JUnit dependencies) instead of TestNG all works fine. Even when I recreated in my IDEA all test classes with proper test framework (TestNG) it doesn't work well. Actually the problem is in `PowerMock`.

Here is my simple code for testing

```
public class Employee {
    public static int count(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

My service class under test

```
public class EmployeeService {
   public int getEmployeeCount(){
       return Employee.count();
   }
}
```

And finally my test code

```
@PrepareForTest(Employee.class)
public class EmployeeServiceTestNGTest {

    @Test
    public void should_return_count_of_employee_using_the_domain_class() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Employee.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Employee.count()).thenReturn(1000);

        EmployeeService employeeService = new EmployeeService();
        Assert.assertEquals(1000, employeeService.getEmployeeCount());
    }
}
```

And my pom.xml with all dependencies:

```
    <properties>
        <powermock.version>1.5.5</powermock.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-testng-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My stacktrace

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at il.arri.powermock.example.Employee.count(Employee.java:9)
    at il.arri.powermock.example.EmployeeServiceTestNGTest.should_return_count_of_employee_using_the_domain_class(EmployeeServiceTestNGTest.java:14)
```

UPD

I changed my test class to

@PrepareForTest(Employee.class)
public class EmployeeServiceTestNGTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

```
@Test
public void should_return_count_of_employee_using_the_domain_class() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Employee.class);
    PowerMockito.when(Employee.count()).thenReturn(1000);

    EmployeeService employeeService = new EmployeeService();
    Assert.assertEquals(1000, employeeService.getEmployeeCount());
}

@ObjectFactory
public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
    return new PowerMockObjectFactory();
}
```

}

But it still has an error:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
An error occurred while instantiating class il.arri.powermock.example.EmployeeServiceTestNGTest: null
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:398)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:299)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:115)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:200)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:120)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:160)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:141)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:271)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:575)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:159)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:113)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.addClassesToModify(MockClassLoader.java:133)
    at org.powermock.modules.testng.internal.PowerMockClassloaderObjectFactory.newInstance(PowerMockClassloaderObjectFactory.java:81)
    at org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory.newInstance(PowerMockObjectFactory.java:42)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:387)
    ... 26 more
```

UPD (Solution):

When I removed this dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-testng-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

All works green :)

Comment: Solved! In my pom.xml file was redundant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't that UnsupportedOperationException supposed to be thrown?

You're telling it to throw that exception in your static count() method.

You can have the unit test expect that a specific exception will be thrown.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the rest of your post.

Glad you got it working.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Frankly to solve my problem I need to change a `pom.xml` file which has a redundant dependencies such as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-testng-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

I need to add `PowerMockObjectFactory` support as well

```
@ObjectFactory
public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
    return new PowerMockObjectFactory();
}
```

And the last thing is to extends from `PowerMockTestCase` class.

```
@PrepareForTest(Employee.class)
public class EmployeeServiceTestNGTest extends PowerMockTestCase {...}
```

Only in this case it works fine and green.